# Freeradius Crypt-Password authentication

Tags: freeradius

In radcheck table of freeradius mysql database, I can add few type of password.

For crypt password, where can I store the salt?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the salt is prepended to the hash automatically by the crypt function, so you don't need to store it separately.

If you want everything to 'just work', you should be able to use the following format:

```
Password-With-Header := '{crypt}<crypt output>'
```

Then:

```
authorize {
    sql
    pap
}
```